# Is there a way to get reactions on an old message in DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm using DiscordJs V12.3.1 and I'm trying to return a list of users that have reacted to an old message. (One that was created before the bot was started).

In my current implementation, I get the fetch the message by ID, map through all reactions, then fetch the reaction, and finally map through the users in the reaction.

```
let cacheChannel = msg.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID); 
if(cacheChannel){
    cacheChannel.messages.fetch(messageID).then(reactionMessage => {                
        reactionMessage.reactions.cache.map(async function(reaction){
            reaction.fetch().then(r => {
                 r.users.cache.map(item => {
                    if(!item.bot) console.log(item.id);                         
                })                        
            })  
        });                                  
    });          
}
```

The above code works for any reactions that were made since the bot started, however fails to find and users that reacted to the message before the bot was started.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Updated the above code based on Lioness100's comment

EDIT2: Managed to get it working with resolve(), see answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right, managed to get it working with the use of .resolve() rather than fetching or mapping through the cache.

```
var getReactedUsers = async(msg, channelID, messageID, emoji) => {
    let cacheChannel = msg.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID); 
    if(cacheChannel){
        cacheChannel.messages.fetch(messageID).then(reactionMessage => {
            reactionMessage.reactions.resolve(emoji).users.fetch().then(userList => {
                return userList.map((user) => user.id)
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Hopefully that is helpful if anyone has the same issue. (Note: You have to pass the emoji, but you can retrieve a list of reacted emojis by using the method posted in the question or in Lioness' comment)

And thanks to Lioness100 for your responses.

Comment: You're still misusing `Array.prototype.map`. You can change `let users = []; userList.map(userObj => { users.push(userObj.id) }); return users;` to `return userList.map((user) => user.id)`

Comment: Ah yeh good point, not that familiar with js. Cheers for that

Comment: Please keep in mind you can only fetch 100 usernames at a time so you have to amke sure to fetch users on a specific reaction untill you get less than 100, or whatever you set the limit to, users back. The provided answer only is useful if you want to get a subset of up to 100 users of a specific emote reaction

Answer (score 3):

Since [`MessageManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns the message's reactions, but not the users who reacted, you'll have to pair it with [`ReactionUserManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager?scrollTo=fetch). Also, why are you creating another variable for the message when you've already fetched it?

```js
var getReactedUsers = (message) => {
 // fetch the users
 message.reactions.cache.users.fetch().then((users) =>
  // I'm not quite sure what you were trying to accomplish with the original lines
  reaction.cache.map((item) => item.users.cache.array())
 );
};

let cacheChannel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
if (cacheChannel) getReacterUsers(await cacheChannel.messages.fetch(messageID));
```

---

Edit: In your updated code, you're misusing [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) a lot.

```js
let cacheChannel = msg.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID);
if (cacheChannel) {
 cacheChannel.messages.fetch(messageID).then((reactionMessage) => {
  console.log(
   reactionMessage.reactions.cache
    .each(async (reaction) => await reaction.users.fetch())
    .map((reaction) => reaction.users.cache.filter((user) => !user.bot))
    .flat()
  );
 });
}
```

Comment: Ah yeh shouldn't have included the first cache, that's actually just called on 'ready' so further reactions can be logged. Having an issue with `users.fetch()`, comes back as undefined.

Comment: Just retried it with your suggestion, still no luck but I've figured it out a different way using .resolve(). You have to provide the emoji but that can be done using the code above, since it does return that, just not the users. I will post the code as an answer below. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. It worked for me. Oh well, looking forward to seeing the solution you found.

Comment: Ah right that's odd, it works for any reactions sent while the bot was running, just none before that.

Comment: Why are you asking me here?